# How to set a default Radio button using Angular Reactive form in Angular Material 6 and display sections based on selection

Tags: angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-material-6

Want to have two sets of radio buttons one on the start and the other on the end 
Set 1 
op1
op2

Set 2 
op3
op4
op5
I am trying to get the following feature, but stuck needed assistance thanks in advance.
The scenario is 
1)The op1 and op3 should be default selected as the page loads 
2) And once these selected they have section1 to display 
3) Similarly if op2 and op3 selected section2 to display

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-7 m-form__group-sub">
                                                <mat-radio-group (change)="changeComboo($event)" formControlName = "policy_type">
                                                        <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let opt of types" [value]="opt">
                                                                {{opt}}
                                                            </mat-radio-button>
                                                    </mat-radio-group>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-5 m-form__group-sub" (change)="changeComboo($event)" >
                                                <mat-radio-group (change)="changeComboo($event)" formControlName = "cst_type">
                                                        <mat-radio-button value="Option3" >Option3</mat-radio-button>
                                                        <mat-radio-button value="Option4" >Option4</mat-radio-button>
                                                        <mat-radio-button value="Option5" >Option5</mat-radio-button>

                                                    </mat-radio-group>
                                        </div>

                                </div>
```

The above the html part

and the one below is in the component

```
 policy_type: string;

types: string[] = ['Option1', 'Option2']

this.policy_type = this.types.values[1];
```

Comment: Your code example is incomplete and you are not using reactive forms properly. You need a `FormGroup` or `FormArray` object containing `FormControl` objects for each of your mat-radio-groups. The `formControlName` directive should refer to the name of a `FormControl` in the group - if you use a property for that then you need to bind it otherwise it is treated as a literal string e.g.: `[formControlName]="policy_type"` or `formControlName="Option2"` not `formControlName = "policy_type"`. Please read the docs if you need more help: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms.

Comment: @G. Tranter Have defined that under a form group, have missed attaching the code here, and yea while changing the actual names missed changing the formControlName to option instead of policy_type, but if not for this what is missing in my code or how could i accomplish the scenario mentioned above, could you please guide me on the steps to be followed, thanks a lot ...

Comment: Please provide a complete, correct working example.